# How to Scroll to contact us when click "Contact Us" button on modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I was struggling to find a way to make it so when i click "Contact us!" on my modal, it would close the modal then scroll to the Contact Us part.The method i found now also scrolls when i press close, is there a way to fix this. This is the function used!

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#leadworkModal, #tilingModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $("#contact-us").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the issue ("The method i found now also scrolls when i press close, is there a way to fix this."), what is the expected behavior?

Comment: To only scroll to contact us when you click the contact us button, now it scrolls also when you click the close button. I only want the modal to close when you click this.

Comment: Move the function from the `hidden.bs.modal` to a click handler for the close button.

Answer (score 1):

You have to attach an event to the button:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '#contactButton', function (e) {
    if($('#leadworkModal').hasClass('in')) $('#leadworkModal').modal('hide');
    if($('#tilingModal').hasClass('in')) $('#tilingModal').modal('hide');
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $("#contact-us").offset().top
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

If you attach event inside button onclick event (as suggested in comments). It will work only once. Because event still is attached for further.

So I would just check if modal is shown just hide it.

Comment: Good callout on attaching the click handler to the document body!

Comment: Thanks. It's just for a case then elements created dynamically.